# Continuation of the voting button design rollout

Tags: support, user-interface

Please continue to process the voting button design rollout by reverting¹, then applying abstraction.

There is absolutely no obligation whatsoever. If you asked me what I'd wish, then I would say:

Please change the current processing of the new design up/down voting clickable area ("voting buttons") feature by reverting and re-introducing it as a user-toggle.

To the best of my hope, this is a test. If so, then it would already help me if there is an option served to opt out of the test.

In the event that this is not a test, I would feel honored to have the original behavior without much interruption and then becoming able to test the new design as an option in a more controlled manner.

I'd consider it beneficial for the feature if all users registered prior production grade General Availability (GA) are able to opt in. And for those who registered afterward, to opt out, I'd consider beneficial to develop, test and maintain the feature, these later properties also for the earlier user profile.

I'm aware that this is entirely subjective and my own opinion only. That alone and the expression of my feelings in writing should not make anyone feel obligated to even consider it. However, it would be great for me if they, their developers, did. That is just as a note between the lines.

Also, I feel reminded somehow that it may be or could have been helpful to a certain degree to consider showing the mandatory, technically verifiable acceptance criteria for changes like these before the announcement of such changes development for a benefit like saving time until the first results are captured in the hope to release such changes faster. But this only as a note in the margin, while me as a content producer would not be a stakeholder nor addressee of such development documentation, I'm positive for those who are and care, there is a chance to consider towards these honorable goals, and that it then could have a good impact on these kinds of changes both in the future and in retrospective, your mileage may vary.

As I don't have much insight, please excuse me already for making suggestions what is not my business not only if you already do it this way. This was just because it was important to me and most likely because of missing information on my end. The source of truth, this holy grail, remains in the middle of yours, I'm only a bystander, and you get only a more or less random opinion out of the Internet - a medium that is famous to have the most of all random opinions (nowadays even enhanced by artificial intelligence which as we could see discussed on Meta is not always to our benefit).

It is an open secret that you all love to show your commitment and the constant improvements in usability across the whole network of Q&A sites. 
Nevertheless, I'm only suggesting such changes first of all for Stack Overflow (and Meta) as I experienced those there firsthand. You know better what you would love to address across all the sites, if even at all.

I'm not expecting any of my suggestions are practically feasible as I'm not connected in any way, form or shape with the development team. Albeit made with the intention that I'd consider them they would, even the better I would do, I could never know. And those who can make a difference know better the flaws, their cause and know best the fixes. My full respect for them and their work, I'm full of hope that to hand over my little feedback they will make it turn into something great all-in-all.

I'm looking forward to seeing any other and perhaps some of these changes in the context of the feature after having the opportunity this morning for the first time to practically use the new design. And I'm sorry as the feedback comes that late, you may blame me, it was just that I was not able to use it in this form earlier.

Disclaimer:

The information provided in this posting is my sole personal opinion as a content producer on Stack Overflow. Only it is important to me, does not make me feel it must be important for others the same.

I'm not affiliated with the site. I've not yet received any swag.

---

¹ If reverting is not culturally accepted as one of, if not even the the most easy, fastest and productive ways of applying changes in software development supported by a version control system, consider it only as a description of the previous behavior without any cultural bias.

<sup>*</sup> An earlier version of the post had much more straight forward language which resulted in many misunderstandings, not limited to that this posting was read as a technical bug report, which was not my intention. Also triggering not only some users in wanting to learn more technicalities of what bugged me. However for me not the what the bug, but how to fix, the suggestion I can contribute is more important. My edit now hopefully makes it more clear, that I don't demand the fix this way, it was just what I'd wish, and that my expression in writing. I am always aware that no software is bug free, and that just counting the bugs can lead to unproductive nit-picking. [The inception image is still available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3A7y2.png).

Comment: I _think_ I upvoted your question but I can't see it. Edit: include me in the screenshot!

Comment: _"mandatory, technically verifiable acceptance criteria"_ - it's their site, they don't have to. The current MO seems to be: 1. Create Meta post appearing to ask for input. 2. Ignore most of that input. 3. Go ahead with the change anyway. 4. Do not respond to complaints. 5. Leave years-old bugs affecting many users alone. 6. More changes equal more click-throughs equals more moneys.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Thanks for your comments. Regarding your last remark: I'm not complaining about the reality, this is a fix suggestion or feedback by me which I assume would help, but I'm aware there is no guarantee nor automation that this will help or even fix it.

Comment: They look like buttons now.  We want people to press them, so making them look like buttons is good.  There are some contrast issues, which ought to be fixed, but demanding a revert is unproductive.  Also we really do not need a _setting_ for the button style.  That would be a waste of development time that could be spent making useful features.  If you really hate them, you can fix it client-side in most browsers pretty easily.

Comment: So, wait, what is actually the ___problem___ with the new design?

Comment: @Mod Please don't see my fix suggestion to revert as unproductive, but consider contrary: A revert is easy to do, therefore fast and very productive. Especially when a roll-out identifies not forseen bugs, it is an easy way to calm down and obtain the necessary development pace again to lower the error rate and have confident in the development. Using feature toggles (as somewhat also suggested by user configuration) is another, often also considered productive way. As this is also part of my request, I see no requirement to forcefully misread it but I'm happy to clarify.

Comment: @Cerbrus: The new design is the problem, or to differentiate a bit more, how it is rolled out. I personally miss the option to disable it. This is a fix request.

Comment: _"The new design is the problem"_ How? Why? What's the problem? Do you just not _like_ the new look? It's a minor styling change... Your expectations of how that's rolled out just isn't how Stack Exchange works.

Comment: My comment addressed _both_ the demand to revert _and_ the request for a feature toggle.  I also don't think it's "forcefully misread"ing to describe a post titled "Fix Voting button design by reverting" as "demanding a revert".  Titles should summarize a post.

Comment: @RyanM: Well seeing a revert as unproductive, that's what should not be IMHO. In this and also in all other cases. Reverts are very easy and productive from my perspective. As I had the impression you may have made the association revert = unproductive, and as my fix suggestion here is not made to be unproductive I beg to not read my demanding of a revert to be unproductive at all, but the opposite: productive, as this is what my knowledge about reverts are. If reverts sounds scary to you, please excuse if the wording has offended you and feel invited to read it differently.

Comment: _"Reverts are very easy and productive from my perspective"_ Then how are you ever going to roll out new changes?

Comment: @Cerbrus: When they are done? And not fearing any mistakes, because of reverts. As already commented, they are very productive. Also as commented, and this is especially for webapplications: Feature toggles.

Comment: Instead of focussing on that "revert" word, how about you answer my earlier question: _What is the problem with the new design?_

Comment: Okay, you're reporting this as a "bug" that needs a "fix".  However, as you've now been told multiple times, your post contains no explanation of the bug.  Either edit your post to explain the bug, or edit your post to explain what _specific_ non-bug change you're asking for.

Comment: @RyanM: Maybe you can help me with that. The problem is the new design and the way it has been rolled out, it is not clear to me how this is not in the question text or how could be anything not clear with that. This is nothing complicated, just feedback from me as  a user. Is meta not for that? This no-noise approach is also in the fix suggestion, very simple (at least for the revert I'm aware), nothing complicated, very conservative on how the feature itself can be retained, without discussing any technicalities or focusing on details. Perhaps the word "revert" is too scary in the industry?

Comment: _"It must require Opt-in for users registering before production grade GA, registrations afterwards must be able to opt-out."_ You're not in the position to make any such demands...

Comment: "please show the mandatory, technically verifiable acceptance criteria for changes like these" - [they did](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389359/461068).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Right, that can be easily misread, I use the term "must" in that sentence to describe what acceptance by me would be. On the one hand this is truly demanding, but on the other hand it is not that I feel obliged to receive this outcome. Do you have an idea how I could make this distinct? Precise, short text of my understanding, but not creating the impression of a demand in the sense as if I would be commander in chief, but just to describe how a fix would look to me? Like  the MUST keyword in one of the internet RFCs?

Comment: @F1Krazy: Yes, I'm aware, my remark is addressing the information in that post as much as I could gather it. I was under the impression that no technical acceptance verification test was formulated _before_ starting the development, also it appeared to me that there were no automated acceptance testing during the development. It is my belief, that if the goal of a change is communicated upfront and then a discussion about the verification is done upfront with concrete results is that the development then will create better results, faster.

Comment: And if this is not about the actual design, but about the rollout process, then your question is extremely misleading. Then this isn't a "bug", there's nothing to "fix"...

Comment: You're using a lot of words to essentially say nothing.

Comment: @Cerbrus You might want to know when to stop asking the same question. At the strength that you are pushing for it, one could with less burden have gone to the [Meta SE announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389359/we-are-graduating-the-updated-button-styling-for-vote-arrows) to find a multitude of problems with the design (such as "grabs too much attention", "the selected form is not contrasted enough with the unselected form, making it hard to see", "change in itself creates an accessibility problem", and "does not really provide full compliance with the WCAG").

Comment: The circles are a little on the large size for my taste, other than that... whatever. Not worth the energy to be a keyboard warrior about it.

Comment: @Cerbrus: You're kind of on/off with my question here. You get feedback in comments where I specifically address your question, but then what should I do if you can't find the answer reading it in my comment then? Then you come from the other side and comment "if this is" and then things I do are extremely misleading. This is not helpful for me, because you don't make a suggestion how it would be better "if this is". See my question here as absolutely subjective user-feedback and only as a fix _suggestion_, as it is better to describe things by the way of how the fix than complaining.

Comment: @Enet4 When submitting a bug report, it's the author's responsibility to at least mention that, and preferably link to it. This post is the first I've seen about the redesign. That context should be in the question.

Comment: @hakre You're not answering my question! You've submitted a bug report. You're stating there's something to _fix_. ___WHAT___ is broken? How is it broken? _What_ needs fixing? Explain it, link to it, describe it!

Comment: @Cerbrus: For me, the voting buttons (the two up / down buttons) have degraded. Described by what would fix it for me by asking for it on meta. See it not as a bug report, more a fix request. Yes, it is demanding, and some may read it without respect for the work done. I do respect the work. What the new design is won't change, as featured on meta on the main site recently. If you think there is too little bureaucracy with my question here, I respectfully refuse to go into more details. As someone other wrote, this is not worth to become a keyboard warrior about it.

Comment: _"the voting buttons have degraded"_ Degraded how? What I'm trying to tell you is that you ___need___ to be descriptive when submitting a bug report. You're writing a lot to justify ___not___ being descriptive...

Comment: ___Again___, when submitting a bug report, relevant context should be included _in the question_. That's why your question is closed at the moment. I'm trying to explain to you that this bug report _needs clarification_. Why are you fighting me? I'm fully aware of the flaws in the new design. I'm telling you this bug report is _unclear_.

Comment: **"Also please show the mandatory, technically verifiable acceptance criteria for changes like these before announcing to start developing such a change to prevent unnecessary time spend until first results can be gathered."** What an absolutely entitled statement to make.

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude but I find your writing style very difficult to follow.

Comment: @user438383: Thanks for sharing this openly, and thanks for the feedback much appreciated. This is the second version, and if you would have found it to be rude, I assume you would have shared that too. I mention this because it is the second revision, and "difficult to follow" sounds much better to me than for example "an absolutely entitled statement to make". I prefer if it is difficult to read instead of others think I'm entitled. If it helps you can peek at the first revision, it might be easier to follow in the text, but also easier to misread. I guess it is hardest to get both right.

Comment: _"an absolutely entitled statement to make"_ is about the request, and has ___nothing___ to do with writing style...  Even if rewritten, the request is entitled.

Comment: I beg your pardon @Cerbrus, it has very much to do with my intend, please rest assured I absolutely don't feel entitled. That would be hilarious. The wish is formulated to be helpful for those who do, not for those who discuss what they did, and done to the best of my knowledge with full respect of the work done. I don't think I'm the person who has to tell, I'm just sharing the feedback and add this as context. Developers commonly report that it helps them with their work. YMMV. For you for example it is more important what is to fix. I'm sure, they know best, others confirmed quick.

Comment: Okay secondary thing which I find a little more problematic: selecting a button gives a quite subtle visual change. But all those things are fixable, going for a revert is the hammer approach.

Comment: @Gimby well it'd be nice if the OP would point at _at least_ one reason _why_ the revert is necessary, in the question :D

Comment: @Gimby: If there is bias against reverts in a team, I'd suggest to think about why it is that. It _should_ not be a hammer, but then why is that? What makes it hard to deploy a revision that was already confirmed ready to deploy? The questions then can lead to more direct feedback from the system and how the team interacts with it. If never done, there is great potential to find some low hanging fruits. It can also help to better understand the trust a team has in the process. E.g. reason to do a revert can be - from a developers perspective - to show they are working. Helps running an app.

Comment: @hakre Imagine you've just spent a week building something. That something gets tested and rolled out. Now someone tells you to revert that change. They refuse to say why, they refuse to explain what was wrong.

We're not against "reverting changes" in general. They just need a ___good reason___. _"To show reverting works"_ is not a good reason.

Generally "reverting" something is ___only___ done because something went wrong. "Reverting" is hardly ever the most efficient / productive option. It's usually a ___last resort___ if something can not be fixed.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Only I don't share the reason with you must not mean there is no good reason. That is perhaps the misunderstanding: If you have trust issues in your colleagues, well then this may shadow as cultural bias over reverts, but it should not question a developers good intent of effectively using  the version control system. Take your one week development example and a four working day week: That should be at least four integrations into trunk to test them in production. If anyone of them is to revert, why should that be the last resort?

Comment: @hakre:  You're submitting a bug report here. An explanation of the bug, and a reason to revert is a ___critical___ part of the report. It's mandatory. It's not optional. All your writing about your perceived resistance against reverts is utterly and completely irrelevant. Your request lacks justification. It's ___that simple___.

Comment: @Cerbrus: With all due respect, I'm not submitting a bug report here. It is absolutely not the role I see myself in, nor am I the person to tell the developers how that feature has to work or what I consider wrong with it. As already written, they know better. If they don't see any issue, then there is nothing to fix. Why not relax your thinking?

Comment: Oh I see you changed the tag... I'm not sure how you want "Support" here... This looks more like a "Discussion" post then. Still, you're asking for a revert, and that requires a ___damn good reason___. Please don't tell me to "relax", I'm just using bold text as emphasis...

Comment: Sorry if that came over offending, my apologies. If it helps, take the revert with a grain of salt. At the end of the day, the reason, and I hope you'd also consider it a good one, is to get the feature faster on production, make it easier to develop, test and maintain. If reverts would not work towards these goals, then please, don't do them, also don't trust my words, if it smells or shows that despite what the team has committed itself to, that it does not work, it can be a good reason to question earlier decisions again.

Comment: @Cerbrus you can't expect to choose a false name "Cerbrus" and then not have people associating that with "cerberus" and the accompanying fiery spirit :)

Comment: @Gimby Even worse, I'm Dutch, so that doubles it ;-)

Comment: What is "GA"? [Google Analytics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Analytics)? [General-availability](https://jdk.java.net/17/)? [Genetic algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm)? Do you mean [AGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_general_intelligence)?

Comment: GA is probably [general availability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle#General_availability_(GA)).

Comment: Yes, General availability (GA). Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 15):

Since the question was completely re-written, I'll rewrite my answer:

> Please continue to process the voting button design rollout by reverting¹, then applying abstraction.

There's no "process" to continue. The feature is rolled out.
Besides, for SE to even consider a revert, you'd need to specify ***why***. You need to justify reverting that change before you request that.

> There is absolutely no obligation whatsoever. If you asked me what I'd wish, then I would say:
>
> Please change the current processing of the new design up/down voting clickable area ("voting buttons") feature by reverting and re-introducing it as a user-toggle.

The design is already implemented, there's no more "processing". We can provide feedback and hope SE does something with it, and that's more or less it.

*"Please make it configurable / optional"* is just not viable. It doesn't scale. If every new little ting has to be toggle-able by the user, you end up with an exponential growth in potential UI configurations that are impossible to test, maintain and make sure they don't break.

> To the best of my hope, this is a test. If so, then it would already help me if there is an option served to opt-out of the test.

As I stated, this is not a test, this is just rolled out already.

> In the event that this is not a test, I would feel honored to have the original behavior without much interruption and then becoming able to test the new design as an option in a more controlled manner.

***Again***, it's not a test.

> I'd consider it beneficial for the feature if all users registered prior production grade GA are able to opt in. And for those who registered afterward, to opt out, I'd consider beneficial to develop, test and maintain the feature, these later properties also for the earlier user profile.

That's not how SE works. You can't make everything opt-in, see my earlier explanation.

> I'm aware that this is entirely subjective and my own opinion only. That alone and the expression of my feelings in writing should not make anyone feel obligated to even consider it. However, it would be great for me if they, their developers, did. That is just as a note between the lines.
>
> Also, I feel reminded somehow, that it may be or could have been helpful to a certain degree to consider showing the mandatory, technically verifiable acceptance criteria for changes like these before the announcement of such changes development for a benefit like saving time until the first results are captured in the hope to release such changes faster. But this only as a note in the margin, while me as a content producer would not be a stakeholder nor addressee of such development documentation, I'm positive for those who are and care, there is a chance to consider towards these honorable goals, and that it then could have a good impact on these kinds of changes both in the future and in retrospective, YMMV.

A lot of (rambling) text to say *"I'd like to see acceptance criteria"*. You're not entitled to that, and you're asking for a crapload of bureaucracy to *"release such changes faster"*? That makes no sense.

> As I don't have much insight, please excuse me already for making suggestions what is not my business not only if you already do it this way. This was just because it was important to me and most likely because of missing information on my end. The source of truth, this holy grail, remains in the middle of yours, I'm only a bystander, and you get only a more or less random opinion out of the internet - a medium that is famous to have the most of all random opinions (nowadays even enhanced by artificial intelligence which as we could see discussed on Meta is not always to our benefit).
>
> It is an open secret that you all love to show your commitment and the constant improvements in usability across the whole network of Q&A sites. Nevertheless, I'm only suggesting such changes first of all for Stack Overflow (and Meta) as I experienced those there firsthand. You know better what you would love to address across all the sites, if even at all.

What. The. Actual. Frick is this rambling?

> I'm not expecting any of my suggestions are practically feasible as I'm not connected in any way, form or shape with the development team. Albeit made with the intention that I'd consider them they would, even the better I would do, I could never know. And those who can make a difference know better the flaws, their cause and know best the fixes. My full respect for them and their work, I'm full of hope that to hand over my little feedback they will make it turn into something great all-in-all.
>
> I'm looking forward to seeing any other and perhaps some of these changes in the context of the feature after having the opportunity this morning for the first time to practically use the new design. And I'm sorry as the feedback comes that late, you may blame me, it was just that I was not able to use it in this form earlier.

Stop sucking up.... -.-

> Disclaimer:
>
> The information provided in this posting is my sole personal opinion as a content producer on Stackoverflow. Only it is important to me, does not make me feel it must be important for others the same.
>
> I'm not affiliated with the site. I've not yet received any swag.

Irrelevant disclaimer...

> <sup>1</sup> If reverting is not culturally accepted as one of, if not even the the most easy, fastest and productive ways of applying changes in software development supported by a version control system, consider it only as a description of the previous behavior without any cultural bias.

"Reverting" isn't the problem.
It's the consistent lack of **justification** to revert this change.

You're going into ***excessive*** depth about how you want this design change rolled back, yet you fail to provide even a ***single reason why***, instead rambling on an on about how everyone's so resistant to reverting the change.

Imagine you've just spent a week building something. That something gets tested and rolled out. Now someone tells you to revert that change. They refuse to say why, they refuse to explain what was wrong. We're not against "reverting changes" in general. **They just need a good reason.** "To show reverting works" is not a good reason. Generally "reverting" something is only done because something went wrong. "Reverting" is hardly ever the most efficient / productive option. It's usually a **last resort** if something can not be fixed.

> <sup>*</sup> An earlier version of the post had much more straight forward language which resulted in many misunderstandings, not limited to that this posting was read as a technical bug report, which was not my intention. Also triggering not only some users in wanting to learn more technicalities of what bugged me. However for me not the what the bug but how to fix, the suggestion I can contribute is more important. My edit now hopefully makes it more clear, that I don't demand the fix this way, it was just what I'd whish, and that my expression in writing. I always aware that no software is bug free, and that just counting the bugs can lead to unproductive nit-picking. The inception image is still available.

The straightforward language wasn't the problem. In fact, this edit made your question that much more incomprehensible. I can't describe it better than "rambling"... I get it, effective communication is hard, but you should really try to get to the point.

Now, at the very ***core*** of all the feedback you've gotten, is the repeated request to explain ***why*** the feature should be rolled back.

Even with this ***massive*** wall of text you changed your question into, you ***still*** didn't provide a ***single*** reason...

---

#### Old answer for reference:

> Please fix the new design of the up/down voting clickable area ("voting buttons") by reverting the change.

You might want to specify what is "broken" when requesting a "fix".

> If this a test, please provide an option to opt-out of the test.

Nope, it's a rolled-out feature / update / change.

> If this is not a test, revert, then make it a feature by allowing the user to configure the new design as an option. It must require Opt-in for users registering before production grade GA, registrations afterwards must be able to opt-out.

*"Please make it configurable / optional"* is just not viable. It doesn't scale. If every new little ting has to be toggle-able by the user, you end up with an exponential growth in potential UI configurations that are impossible to test, maintain and make sure they don't break.

> Also please show the mandatory, technically verifiable acceptance criteria for changes like these before announcing to start developing such a change to prevent unnecessary time spend until first results can be gathered.

You're a user, not a product owner. You're in no place to demand this kind of process. That's just simply not how Stack Exchange works, even on larger features. At best, we get asked for feedback first, which may or may not be taken into account.

Comment: The new design is the problem, or to differentiate a bit more, how it is rolled out. I personally miss the option to disable it. This is a fix request. This is not a little thing to me. In case of doubt, it is close to borderline to even meta on this topic for the reality being. But I don't complain and make the fix suggestion instead as there is something to fix.

Comment: _"it is close to borderline to even meta on this topic for the reality being."_ ... whut? Honestly I have no idea what you're talking about @hakre... You ___still___ haven't stated what the actual ___problem___ with the new design is. There's not gonna be an option, there's not gonna be a revert, ___especially___ not if you fail to clarify _why_ that'd be necessary.

Comment: That's a complicated way of writing that apart from the level of a first fast fix, it makes little sense to discuss the feature for itself, given the time it already lives; reality does not suggest otherwise to me - YMMV. And you have kind of a steamy way to ask, please don't conflate your reading of my writing with my commentary, especially when you already realize, that you do not have even a single, positive confirmation of it. Your comment might not have been addressed at all.

Comment: There being two hamburger icons in the top bar, THAT'S a problem. The vote buttons being obtuse is just a petty annoyance.

Comment: @Gimby Oof, I still get those 2 mixed up!